# Sending multiple strings using pipes to child process

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I have a task in Linux and I can't get it work.

I have a program that receives a text file as parameter. It then creates a child process using `fork()` and sends to the child process, line by line the content of the text file received as parameter. The child process needs to count the lines and return to the parent process the number of lines received.

This is what I have until now, but somewhat the child process does not receive all the lines. For my test I used a text file with 9 lines. The parent sent 9 lines as strings but the child process received only 2 or 3 of them.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  char string[80];
  char readbuffer[80];
  int pid, p[2];
  FILE *fp;
  int i=0;
  if(argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Syntax: %s [file_name]\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;    
  }
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(!fp) 
  {    
    printf("Error: File '%s' does not exist.\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
  }
  if(pipe(p) == -1)
  {
    printf("Error: Creating pipe failed.\n");
    exit(0);
  } 
  // creates the child process
  if((pid=fork()) == -1)
  {
   printf("Error: Child process could not be created.\n");
    exit(0);
  }  

  /* Main process */
  if (pid) 
  { 
    // close the read
    close(p[0]);    
    while(fgets(string,sizeof(string),fp) != NULL)
    {                
       write(p[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
       printf("%s\n",string);
    } 

    // close the write
    close(p[1]);
    wait(0);
  }

  // child process
  else 
  {   
    // close the write
    close(p[1]); 

    while(read(p[0],readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer)) != 0) 
    {
      printf("Received string: %s\n", readbuffer);    
    }

    // close the read
    close(p[0]); 
  } 
  fclose(fp);       
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the appropriate tag. Anyway, here's a hint: `read` doesn't stop reading if there's a `'\0'` in the data stream.

Comment: Did the child process receive "2 or 3 lines" or did its `read()` return "2 or 3 *times*"? Those are different scenarios. I'm willing to bet it's the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pipe is a unidirectional interprocess communication channel. You have to create 2 pipes, one to speak to the child process, the other to read data back.

Remember to close the unused side of the pipe on both processes.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending the null terminator to the other process:

```
   write(p[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
```

That makes the result confusing because when you print what you've received, you only see up to the null terminator.

If you do this instead:

```
   write(p[1], string, strlen(string));
```

you should get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You're not counting the number of lines, you're counting the number of times `read(2)` returns.

When using pipes, `read(2)` will pull as much data as possible from the pipe: `min(pipe_available, space_available)`. It doesn't care for newlines, `0` bytes etc. Simple tricks to make it work:

- Use a loop to walk `readbuffer` and look for `\n`
- Use `fdopen` + `fgets` (I have a feeling this is probably flawed)

Comment: His code as written doesn't send `'\n'` to the child process. He has to look for `'\0'`.

Comment: @celtschk Doesn't `fgets` leave the `\n` in ? I think it does *No additional characters are read after a new-line character (**which is retained**) or after end-of-file*. - 7.21.7.2

Comment: Oops, you're right. I wasn't aware that `fgets` differs from `gets` in this respect (who invented *that* interface!?)

Comment: @celtschk I didn't even know `gets` didn't include the newline! Ha, **nice** find!

Answer (score 1):

look into manpage of pipe ( man 2 pipe ), the program you're trying to write is as an example there, compare it with yours :)